# PHP seems to be refusing to connect to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, mamp

```
<?php

function redirect_to_index_with_error(){
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=index.php">';
}

function go_to_home(){
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=home.php">';
}

$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); echo $email;
$pwd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
echo $pwd;
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password=MD5('$pwd')";
echo "query variable created.";

mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
echo "connected."; //nothing

mysql_select_db("mcp") or die(mysql_error());

$results = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($results) == 0){
    redirect_to_index_with_error();
    exit();
}

$userID = null;
$name = null;
$school = null;
$mod = null;

while($user = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
    $userID = $user['ID'];
    $name = $user['Name'];
    $school = $user['School'];
    if($user['Mod'] == '1')
        $mod = true;
    else
        $mod = false;

}
if(!isset($_SESSION))
    session_start();

//set session variables
$_SESSION["userID"] = $userID;
$_SESSION["name"] = $name;
$_SESSION["school"] = $school;
$_SESSION["mod?"] = $mod;

go_to_home();
exit();
?>
```

PHP echos everything up until "connected". It's not even showing a mysql error. I've had this code work flawlessly on Windows with WAMP, but not on Mac with MAMP. I've verified that the servers are running, so I can't tell what the problem is. I'm using PHP 5.3.6.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be outputting anything if everything goes well, does it?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to post the entire code. i'll do that right now.

Comment: what this code supposed to echo after "connected"?

Comment: Have you verified and made sure that the user you are looking for actually does exist?

Comment: yes, i checked with phpMyAdmin. shane's answer fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection needs to be established before you call `mysql_real_escape_string()`

So move `mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());` to the top.

Answer (score 1):

you have to call mysql_real_escape_string() after connect.
otherwise this function returns an empty string and your query fails.

though it raises an error but it seems you haven't seen that.
So, you ought to either turn displaying errors on or peek error logs - it's impossible to program without ability to see error messages

Also, you have to improve your formal logic.
To make a statement like "PHP seems to be refusing to connect to MySQL" youi have to verify it first. Connect is just a single line and returns a value.
You can verify this value and make a certain conclusion.
But running whole code of several dozens of lines and making statements about just one makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `mysql_connect()` statement above everything else.

```
// put this at the TOP
mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as everyone else mentioned, see this note:
http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string#refsect1-function.mysql-real-escape-string-notes

Also, you should see errors, in development, at least.
See: [error_reporting()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: not only in development. error_reporting should be always at max

Comment: Right, what I meant to say is that on a live site, the error output should be sent to a log file instead of being displayed on the screen while in development, the output is easiest to view when displayed on the screen (unless you have a terminal with `tail -f /path/to/log` running :))